# Можно ли в jstl использовать переменную javascript?

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, jstl

Здравствуйте! Я совсем новичок в **java ee**, проблема в следующем: в сервлете я передаю атрибут `objects`, который является коллекцией. Мне нужно сделать меню, чтобы при клике по кнопке подгружалась информация по объекту. В данном примере при выполнении всегда выводится элемент с индексом 0.

Можно ли использовать переменную из **JS** в `jstl`? Или может быть посоветуете другой способ, как это лучше реализовать?

```js
<script type = "text/javascript">
  function loadInfo(button) {
    var index = button.value;
    $('.info').remove();
    $('.main').append('<div class="info"></div>');
    $('.info').append('<c:out value="${objects.get(index).address}" />');
  }
</script>
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  <c:forEach var="object" items="${objects}" varStatus="сounter">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" value="${сounter.index}" id="objSelect" onclick="loadInfo(this)">${object.name}</button>
  </c:forEach>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Инструкции JSTL выполняются на сервере, инструкции JavaScript на клиенте. Соответственно конструкция

```
$('.info').append('<c:out value="${objects.get(index).address}" />');
```

бессмысленна. Можно сделать так:

**some_page.jsp**

```
<div class="menu">
  <c:forEach var="object" items="${objects}" varStatus="сounter">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="objSelect${сounter.index}" data-addr="${object.address}">${object.name}</button>
  </c:forEach>
</div>
<div class="main">
    <div class="info"></div>
</div>
```

**some_script.js**

```
$('.menu button').click(function(event) {
    $('.info').html($(this).data('addr'));
});
```

Comment: Большое Вам спасибо, это как раз то, что нужно)